# soy milk production with no beany flavor

Tags: beans, drinks, soy, soymilk

does anyone know how big industries like Silk are producing soy drinks with no beany flavor? I read that a you should soak beans in boioling water (which temperature? for how many minutes?) in order to disable some enzymes. Then you should rinse the beans (is there anything to be careful to?)
Finally you have to remove the skins.

what else?

How to bring a better texture?

Comment: There are, in my experience, two kinds of soy milk. 1) is what we in the west are accustomed to (which primarily come from grocery stores and 2) what people in asia are familiar with, which is typically drunk warm. I assume you are going for the first one. What strain of beans are you using (this matters too)? Also are you using a steamer to extract the milk, or a "pressure cooker-esque" thing (I can't remember the name...).

Comment: I'm talking about the industrial -such as in UHT tetra brik- products...so I guess the first type you mentioned. I'm not sure about the strain I'm using. this is a normal raw material, harvested in Italy

Answer (score 1):

Ok - given your clarification try the following:

1. Rinse your beans before handling, through transport and storage dust accrues and can increase their natural nutty flavour.
2. Blanche them in boiling water for roughly 90s. Then strain and rinse under cool water in your sink (have a catch of some kind to prevent bits of going down the drain).
3. Cook as normal but add a pinch of sugar (can't say for sure how much, as I don't know the volume you are making).
4. When cooked/milked, strain again, and then let it rest in the fridge until cool.

This is exactly how I make mine (I make both varieties though), and there is very little  (if any) beany taste left. In fact, sometimes as a result (mind you I use the same beans everytime) it comes a little bit nutty.

Comment: I'll make some trials and then I'll come back to you with my feedbacks!

Comment: I found the sugar bit to be a lot of trial and error. Good luck!

Comment: Are you soaking the beans for 10-12 hours after you blanche them?

Comment: @EvanR I am not.

Comment: @JCrosby So, you just blanch them for 90 seconds and that's it?

Comment: @EvanR, yes. That is all I did.

Answer (score 1):

From [Serious Eats](https://www.seriouseats.com/2018/06/a-brief-history-of-soy-milk-the-future-food-of-yesterday.html):

> The quality of commercial soy milk had also improved, thanks to food science. In the late 1960s, flavor researchers at Cornell University had definitively identified an enzyme called lipoxygenase as the source of soy milk’s reviled beany flavor. When soaked soybeans were ground at temperatures below 180°F (82°C), lipoxygenase went on a catalytic rampage, converting fatty acids into a whole spectrum of rancid-tasting and unpleasant molecules. Scientists also pinpointed oligosaccharides, or complex sugars, as the culprits behind soy-milk flatulence. By the 1970s, it was possible to manufacture a bland, creamy, and fartless soy milk—a truly inoffensive beverage, suitable for mass consumption.

Answer (score 1):

While all these answers are good, I will add in something that hasn't been mentioned! What we do in my home for homemade soyabean is that we usually will add in aromatics such as pandas leaves, which will most definitely enhance the flavour and also get rid the "beany" taste. You can probably get these in your asian food market.

[image]

Comment: YES! I have read about these, but we (in my home) haven't used them so I couldn't speak to them personally. Thanks for touching on this.

Comment: @JCrosby You should try it some day! The difference is huge :)